# Meaning of @ zero_extendqisi2

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, arm

I was wondering what the actual meaning of `@ zero_extendqisi2` in gcc assembly output was and also the usage. I couldn't find what qisi stands for or anything along those lines.

For context, the line is `ldrb  r3, [fp, #-9]   @ zero_extendqisi2` and this is ARM on a Raspberry Pi Zero W, compiled with GCC.  For example, when reloading an `unsigned char` with conversion to `int`, with optimization disabled, with GCC9.2 with no options.  https://godbolt.org/z/7xnfqh.  Older GCC all the way to the earliest on Godbolt (4.5) and presumably earlier print the same comment.

Comment: To whoever closed this: if you don’t know then pass on rather than closing without having subject knowledge. The question is rather clear if you actually know what’s going on. Closing something because *you* are unfamiliar with it is reprehensible.

Comment: In GCC terminology, QI = "quarter int" = 1 byte for a target like ARM with 4-byte int.  SI = single int.  So I assume this would be something like `uxtb`.  But can you show the full context where you saw this comment?  I don't see it in https://godbolt.org/z/T9586M.  IDK what the `2` suffix might mean.  double-int (8-bytes) would be DI.

Comment: Peter, thanks for answering my question. I have edited my post for clarity. I don't know why my post was closed. This is my first Stack Overflow post.

Comment: Interesting, yeah easy enough to reproduce with a short [mcve] : https://godbolt.org/z/7xnfqh (like you could put in your question as a more convincing reason for someone to cast a final reopen vote).  Interesting that GCC prints that comment even *without* `-fverbose-asm`, like it was maybe part of the template string in the `.md` machine definition file.  Maybe it's there to help debug GCC internals?  As far as actual *effect*, it's just a comment.

Comment: Peter, appreciate the response. I searched the internet for a while with no luck. My ARM assembly professor had us search this for extra credit. While I wasn't using that GCC flag, I was using -g so I could debug in GDB. I was also using -O0 for no optimization. While it is just a comment, we were all curious as to what exactly it meant. Thanks again.

Comment: I didn't expect it was something that would be easy to google, but asking a good question means including some context so people that want to answer  1. can see what general kind of thing you're doing 2. can reproduce it themselves to play around more if it turns out to be obscure.  So I would have included: a C function that could be compiled, a GCC version number and options I used, and the asm output for the function.  Showing the full line with the ldrb instruction is fine for the last part, and I guess we don't really need any more detail now that it's answered, but keep in mind next time

Comment: I edited your question to fix those problems.

Answer (score 3):

This is an [RTL](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/RTL.html#RTL) instruction name, included in the [Standard Names list of the GCC internals manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Standard-Names.html) under `zero_extendmn2`.  Here `m,n` are the [machine modes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Machine-Modes.html#Machine-Modes) `qi` and `si`, which are respectively a byte and a 32-bit integer.  So this is GCC's indication that it is generating an instruction which takes a byte (here loaded from memory) and zero-extends it into a 32-bit integer (here in the register r3).  Which is exactly what the ARM `ldrb` instruction does.

I don't know what the 2 stands for, but it's apparently part of GCC's naming convention.

As Peter points out, it's a little odd that GCC would include such a comment in the assembly without `-fverbose-asm`.  Indeed the comment is coded in as part of the template string in the machine description file, [`arm.md`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/arm/arm.md;h=1a8e498ba4c34dbbf87b2b205adf6c5c0a74ca6c;hb=HEAD#l5643). It could have been a debugging aid that some GCC developer added and then forgot to take out.

(If you submit this for your assignment, please cite this post properly.)

Comment: Indeed, the primary extension is `andsi` where the 8-bit value is in a 32-bit register.  The 2nd variant seems to be if it is a memory operand, the `ldrb` [comes in sign-extended and non-extending versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430522/can-someone-explain-the-following-load-and-store-instructions-as-part-of-the-arm).  If these are incorporated in the answer, my comments are obsolete.

Comment: @artlessnoise: It's definitely unrelated to being paired with `strb`.  That's just a coincidence of using `-O0` to get gcc to emit a zero-extending load.  There are other ways, e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/bs3MKc passing a `char` by reference to a function, then reading the value, which repros the result even with `-O3` with no `strb` in sight anywhere in this function.  I haven't had any luck getting GCC to emit a similar comment for a register operation.

Comment: @artlessnoise: I don't think the "two instructions" hypothesis fits.  First, the name is common across all target architectures in GCC, and there's no reason to think they would all need two instructions.  Second, ARM doesn't even need two instructions in this case; `ldrb` does zero extending all by itself.  See for instance Peter's example, or even simpler https://godbolt.org/z/3PTMvP where GCC generates it standing alone.  "Variants" would make sense except that all the extension insns seem to end in 2 and I don't see any 1s.

Comment: Thanks. My 2nd comment (now first) tried to clarify that is seemed like a variant and not two instructions; the fact it is a memory operand is addressed more directly by Peter's specific example that this is wrong.  I believe that one is implicit so there are no `sign_extendqisi1` as many instructions without variants  would need to be updated as a 2nd variant is discovered/needed causing a lot of code churn.

Comment: Appreciate all the answers. What confused us the most was the 2 suffix, but it seems like it's just a random convention. I will of course cite everything here. You guys rock!